# ItextSharp Add lines to PDF and convert into bytes without saving it.

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext, pdf-generation

I have a method that gets a pdf and adds's lines in that pdf and then creates a new pdf and saves it in a path that's given to it. Now I don't want to save that new file in a path instead I want to convert it into bytes and send in Emails how can I do that I tried a couple of methods but it all ways look for path says no path found here is the code.

```
     protected void CreatePDF()
    {

        string Oldfile = @"C:\BlankPDFt.pdf"; // Gets the Template / The actualy agreement Letter
      //  (new FileInfo("C:/Documents/Docs.pdf")).Directory.Create(); // Go create this folder if it's not there
      string NewFile = "C:/Documents/Docs.pdf";
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(Oldfile);
        iTextSharp.text.Rectangle Size = reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1);
        Document document = new Document(Size);
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(NewFile , FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write); // This is where it all ways look for new file path
 i dont want it to save instead convert to bytes but wont work.
        PdfWriter weiter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fs);
        document.Open();
        PdfContentByte cb = weiter.DirectContent;
        PdfImportedPage page = weiter.GetImportedPage(reader, 1);
        cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);
        BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
        cb.SetColorFill(BaseColor.BLACK);
        cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 12);
        cb.BeginText();
     //   string Signatur = "Some texts"; // adds this text to that pdf 
      cb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, "Here", 335, 90, 0); // Insert the signature
        cb.EndText();
    }
```

Comment: Try creating the file in a temp folder and deleting it later?

Comment: Good idea! but unfortunately, that's not a proper way to approach this method it will only slow down the process. Plus  I will have to look for that document and delete what if there were 40 of them created same time and which one would it go for deleting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `PdfWriter.GetInstance()` method accepts an `InputStream` as its second argument. Instead of passing a `FileStream` you should  pass it a `MemoryStream`.

```
MemoryStream memory_stream = new MemoryStream();
PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, memory_stream );
...
document.Close();
byte[] pdf_bytes = memory_stream.ToArray();
```

Comment: Let me try this and the byte[] pdf_bytes = baos.toByteArray(); should it be only toarraay ? its giving error on this ByteArrayOutputStream does not contains a defination of tobytearray

Comment: Yes, see my update. I had originally written the snippet in Java.

Comment: Worked Thanks! Now it does not save any where